# Why is Install button still greyed out in absence of screen filter apps?

Tags: installation, side-loading

As you can see in the image, the Install button is greyed out. I have Unknown sources enabled and no screen filter app or Twilight or Lux are installed in my phone.

[image: screenshot]

I am using Samsung 6 Edge latest version.

Comment: Is there any other way I can download the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means Your Device Doesn't Support the app